# Extracting variable number of lines after pattern matching from other file

Tags: linux, awk, sed, grep

Recently, I have a list of values stored in a file called Name.txt

```
XP_037759835.2
XP_037759838.2
XP_037759836.2
```

This file is used for finding several sequences in another file called
sequence.faa

```
>NP_001277599.1 actin, alpha cardiac muscle 1 [Chelonia mydas]
MCDDEETTALVCDNGSGLVKAGFAGDDAPRAVFPSIVGRPRHQGVMVGMGQKDSYVGDEAQSKRGILTLKYPIEHGIITN
WDDMEKIWHHTFYNELRVAPEEHPTLLTEAPLNPKANREKMTQIMFETFNVPAMYVAIQAVLSLYASGRTTGIVLDSGDG
VTHNVPIYEGYALPHAIMRLDLAGRDLTDYLMKILTERGYSFVTTAEREIVRDIKEKLCYVALDFENEMATAASSSSLEK
SYELPDGQVITIGNERFRCPETLFQPSFIGMESAGIHETTYNSIMKCDIDIRKDLYANNVLSGGTTMYPGIADRMQKEIT
ALAPSTMKIKIIAPPERKYSVWIGGSILASLSTFQQMWISKQEYDEAGPSIVHRKCF
>NP_001277600.1 cytochrome P450 1A [Chelonia mydas]
MSLLGSQGIISVTEILIASAVFCLTFMVIRSFRQQIPKGLKRLPGPRGYPLIGNLLELGSNPHLTLTQMSQKYGDVMQIR
IGTRPVLVLSGLDTIKQALVKQGEDFMGRPDLYSFHHVADGQSLTFSTDSGEVWRARRKLAQNALKTFSVSPSPNSSSTC
LLEEHVSKEADYLVRKLLQLMEEKKRFDPFRYVVVSVANVICAMCFGNRYDHDDQELLSIVNVTEEFGDVAASGNPVDFI
PVLQYLPNRTMKKFMEFNTRFLRLLQDIVKEHYESFEKDNIRDITDSLIEQSQENKVEANANIQLPKGKIINLVNDLFGA
GFDTVTTALSWSLMYLVTYPDIQKKIQEELDQTIGRERRPRLSDRPMLPYTEAFILEMFRHSSFLPFTIPHCTTKDTVLN
GYYIPKDLCVFVNQWQVNHDEKLWKEPSRFDPERFLRAGGTEVNKTDGEKILIFGLGKRKCLGETIARWEVFLFLTTLLQ
QLEFSISDGQKVDMTPLYGLTMKHKRCEHFQVKQRFPIQSSE
>NP_001277601.1 tumor susceptibility gene 101 protein [Chelonia mydas]
MAVRESELKKMLAKYKYRDLTVQETTSVITQYKDLKPVMDAYVFNDGSSRDLMSLTGTIPVPYRGNTYNIPICLWLLDTY
PFNPPICFVKPTSSMTIKTGKHVDANGKIYLPYLHEWKHPQSDLIGLIQIMIVVFGEEPPVFSRPTISTSFQPYQATGPP
NTSYMPGMPSGISPYPPGHPPNPSGYPGYPYPPGGPFPATTSGQHYTSQPPVTTVGPSRDGTISEDTIRASRISAVSDKL
RWRMKEEMDRAQAELNALKRTEEDLKKGHQKLEEMVTRLDHEVAEVDKNIELLKKKDEELSSALEKMENQSENNDIDEVI
IPTAPLYKQILNLYAEENAIEDTIFYLGEALRRGVIDLDVFLKHVRLLSRKQFQLRALMQKARKTAGLSDLY
>XP_037759835.2 splicing factor 1 isoform X1 [Chelonia mydas]
MAATGANATPLGKLHPPPPPGKPGYPMPPPGPPGLVLPGPPPPPPPGPGQAQAALLGPMAAAAYPFAALPPPPPPPPPPP
PPPQPQPPPQQPQPPPPPPPPPPPQQQQPPPQAGGPQPPPQYGQYRYPSPPPPPQGHEQQQPPPPQQQQQDESGPGGGSN
HDFPNKKRKRSRWNQDTMEQKTVIPGMPTVIPPGLTREQERAYIVQLQIEDLTRKLRTGDLGIPPNPEDRSPSPEPIYNS
EGKRLNTREFRTRKKLEEERHNLITEMVALNPDFKPPADYKPPATRVSDKVMIPQDEYPEINFVGLLIGPRGNTLKNIEK
ECNAKIMIRGKGSVKEGKVGRKDGQMLPGEDEPLHALVTANTMENVKKAVEQIRNILKQGIETPEDQNDLRKMQLRELAR
LNGTLREDDNRILRPWQSAETRSITNTTVCTKCGGAGHIASDCKFSRPGDPQSAQDKARMDKEYLSLMAELGEAPVPASV
GSSSGPTNTPLSSGPRPSGPGNNPPPPNRPPWMNSGPSDNRPYHGMHGGPGGPGGPHNFHHPMPNMGGHGGHPMQHNPNG
PPPWMQPHHPPMNQGPHPPGHPGPHHMDQYLGNTPVGSGVYRLHQGKGMMPPPMGMMAPPPPPPSGQPPPPPSGPLPPWQ
QQQQPPPPPPSSSMASSTPLPWQQNTTTTTTTSAGTGSIPPWQQQGAAVAASTGAPQMQGNPSMVPLPPGVQPPLPPGAP
PPPPPPPPGSAGMMYAPPPPPPPMDPSNFVTMMGMGVPALPPFGMPPAPPPPPPQN
>XP_037759838.2 splicing factor 1 isoform X4 [Chelonia mydas]
MAATGANATPLGKLHPPPPPGKPGYPMPPPGPPGLVLPGPPPPPPPGPGQAQAALLGPMAAAAYPFAALPPPPPPPPPPP
PPPQPQPPPQQPQPPPPPPPPPPPQQQQPPPQAGGPQPPPQYGQYRYPSPPPPPQGHEQQQPPPPQQQQQDESGPGGGSN
HDFPNKKRKRSRWNQDTMEQKTVIPGMPTVIPPGLTREQERAYIVQLQIEDLTRKLRTGDLGIPPNPEDRSPSPEPIYNS
EGKRLNTREFRTRKKLEEERHNLITEMVALNPDFKPPADYKPPATRVSDKVMIPQDEYPEINFVGLLIGPRGNTLKNIEK
ECNAKIMIRGKGSVKEGKVGRKDGQMLPGEDEPLHALVTANTMENVKKAVEQIRNILKQGIETPEDQNDLRKMQLRELAR
LNGTLREDDNRILRPWQSAETRSITNTTVCTKCGGAGHIASDCKFSRPGDPQSAQDKARMDKEYLSLMAELGEAPVPASV
GSSSGPTNTPLSSGPRPSGPGNNPPPPNRPPWMNSGPSDNRPYHGMHGGPGGPGGPHNFHHPMPNMGGHGGHPMQHNPNG
PPPWMQPHHPPMNQGPHPPGHPGPHHMDQYLGNTPVGSGVYRLHQGKDTTTTTTTSAGTGSIPPWQQQGAAVAASTGAPQ
MQGNPSMVPLPPGVQPPLPPGAPPPPPPPPPGSAGMMYAPPPPPPPMDPSNFVTMMGMGVPALPPFGMPPAPPPPPPQN
>XP_037759836.2 splicing factor 1 isoform X2 [Chelonia mydas]
MAATGANATPLGKLHPPPPPGKPGYPMPPPGPPGLVLPGPPPPPPPGPGQAQAALLGPMAAAAYPFAALPPPPPPPPPPP
PPPQPQPPPQQPQPPPPPPPPPPPQQQQPPPQAGGPQPPPQYGQYRYPSPPPPPQGHEQQQPPPPQQQQQDESGPGGGSN
HDFPNKKRKRSRWNQDTMEQKTVIPGMPTVIPPGLTREQERAYIVQLQIEDLTRKLRTGDLGIPPNPEDRSPSPEPIYNS
EGKRLNTREFRTRKKLEEERHNLITEMVALNPDFKPPADYKPPATRVSDKVMIPQDEYPEINFVGLLIGPRGNTLKNIEK
ECNAKIMIRGKGSVKEGKVGRKDGQMLPGEDEPLHALVTANTMENVKKAVEQIRNILKQGIETPEDQNDLRKMQLRELAR
LNGTLREDDNRILRPWQSAETRSITNTTVCTKCGGAGHIASDCKFSRPGDPQSAQDKARMDKEYLSLMAELGEAPVPASV
GSSSGPTNTPLSSGPRPSGPGNNPPPPNRPPWMNSGPSDNRPYHGMHGGPGGPGGPHNFHHPMPNMGGHGGHPMQHNPNG
PPPWMQPHHPPMNQGPHPPGHPGPHHMDQYLGNTPVGSGVYRLHQGKGMMPPPMGMMAPPPPPPSGQPPPPPSGPLPPWQ
QQQQPPPPPPSSSMASSTPLPWQQSEYDDHHHHERWHRVHPAMAAAGGCGGGFYGGPADARQPLHGPFASRGPASAAARG
PAAAAAAAAWLRGHDVRPAPSPAPHGPF
```

The desire output is the names XP_037759835.2, XP_037759838.2,  XP_037759836.2 will be matched and their sequence below will be extracted out

```
>XP_037759835.2 splicing factor 1 isoform X1 [Chelonia mydas]
MAATGANATPLGKLHPPPPPGKPGYPMPPPGPPGLVLPGPPPPPPPGPGQAQAALLGPMAAAAYPFAALPPPPPPPPPPP
PPPQPQPPPQQPQPPPPPPPPPPPQQQQPPPQAGGPQPPPQYGQYRYPSPPPPPQGHEQQQPPPPQQQQQDESGPGGGSN
HDFPNKKRKRSRWNQDTMEQKTVIPGMPTVIPPGLTREQERAYIVQLQIEDLTRKLRTGDLGIPPNPEDRSPSPEPIYNS
EGKRLNTREFRTRKKLEEERHNLITEMVALNPDFKPPADYKPPATRVSDKVMIPQDEYPEINFVGLLIGPRGNTLKNIEK
ECNAKIMIRGKGSVKEGKVGRKDGQMLPGEDEPLHALVTANTMENVKKAVEQIRNILKQGIETPEDQNDLRKMQLRELAR
LNGTLREDDNRILRPWQSAETRSITNTTVCTKCGGAGHIASDCKFSRPGDPQSAQDKARMDKEYLSLMAELGEAPVPASV
GSSSGPTNTPLSSGPRPSGPGNNPPPPNRPPWMNSGPSDNRPYHGMHGGPGGPGGPHNFHHPMPNMGGHGGHPMQHNPNG
PPPWMQPHHPPMNQGPHPPGHPGPHHMDQYLGNTPVGSGVYRLHQGKGMMPPPMGMMAPPPPPPSGQPPPPPSGPLPPWQ
QQQQPPPPPPSSSMASSTPLPWQQNTTTTTTTSAGTGSIPPWQQQGAAVAASTGAPQMQGNPSMVPLPPGVQPPLPPGAP
PPPPPPPPGSAGMMYAPPPPPPPMDPSNFVTMMGMGVPALPPFGMPPAPPPPPPQN
>XP_037759838.2 splicing factor 1 isoform X4 [Chelonia mydas]
MAATGANATPLGKLHPPPPPGKPGYPMPPPGPPGLVLPGPPPPPPPGPGQAQAALLGPMAAAAYPFAALPPPPPPPPPPP
PPPQPQPPPQQPQPPPPPPPPPPPQQQQPPPQAGGPQPPPQYGQYRYPSPPPPPQGHEQQQPPPPQQQQQDESGPGGGSN
HDFPNKKRKRSRWNQDTMEQKTVIPGMPTVIPPGLTREQERAYIVQLQIEDLTRKLRTGDLGIPPNPEDRSPSPEPIYNS
EGKRLNTREFRTRKKLEEERHNLITEMVALNPDFKPPADYKPPATRVSDKVMIPQDEYPEINFVGLLIGPRGNTLKNIEK
ECNAKIMIRGKGSVKEGKVGRKDGQMLPGEDEPLHALVTANTMENVKKAVEQIRNILKQGIETPEDQNDLRKMQLRELAR
LNGTLREDDNRILRPWQSAETRSITNTTVCTKCGGAGHIASDCKFSRPGDPQSAQDKARMDKEYLSLMAELGEAPVPASV
GSSSGPTNTPLSSGPRPSGPGNNPPPPNRPPWMNSGPSDNRPYHGMHGGPGGPGGPHNFHHPMPNMGGHGGHPMQHNPNG
PPPWMQPHHPPMNQGPHPPGHPGPHHMDQYLGNTPVGSGVYRLHQGKDTTTTTTTSAGTGSIPPWQQQGAAVAASTGAPQ
MQGNPSMVPLPPGVQPPLPPGAPPPPPPPPPGSAGMMYAPPPPPPPMDPSNFVTMMGMGVPALPPFGMPPAPPPPPPQN
>XP_037759836.2 splicing factor 1 isoform X2 [Chelonia mydas]
MAATGANATPLGKLHPPPPPGKPGYPMPPPGPPGLVLPGPPPPPPPGPGQAQAALLGPMAAAAYPFAALPPPPPPPPPPP
PPPQPQPPPQQPQPPPPPPPPPPPQQQQPPPQAGGPQPPPQYGQYRYPSPPPPPQGHEQQQPPPPQQQQQDESGPGGGSN
HDFPNKKRKRSRWNQDTMEQKTVIPGMPTVIPPGLTREQERAYIVQLQIEDLTRKLRTGDLGIPPNPEDRSPSPEPIYNS
EGKRLNTREFRTRKKLEEERHNLITEMVALNPDFKPPADYKPPATRVSDKVMIPQDEYPEINFVGLLIGPRGNTLKNIEK
ECNAKIMIRGKGSVKEGKVGRKDGQMLPGEDEPLHALVTANTMENVKKAVEQIRNILKQGIETPEDQNDLRKMQLRELAR
LNGTLREDDNRILRPWQSAETRSITNTTVCTKCGGAGHIASDCKFSRPGDPQSAQDKARMDKEYLSLMAELGEAPVPASV
GSSSGPTNTPLSSGPRPSGPGNNPPPPNRPPWMNSGPSDNRPYHGMHGGPGGPGGPHNFHHPMPNMGGHGGHPMQHNPNG
PPPWMQPHHPPMNQGPHPPGHPGPHHMDQYLGNTPVGSGVYRLHQGKGMMPPPMGMMAPPPPPPSGQPPPPPSGPLPPWQ
QQQQPPPPPPSSSMASSTPLPWQQSEYDDHHHHERWHRVHPAMAAAGGCGGGFYGGPADARQPLHGPFASRGPASAAARG
PAAAAAAAAWLRGHDVRPAPSPAPHGPF
```

I was thinking is to extract a certain amount of lines after a pattern from Name.txt has matched in sequence.faa. The problem is I'm not sure whether awk, sed or grep can accomplish such output. Can anyone give me some solutions or directions to tackle this issue?
Ps: The above files are examples, not the actual file that Im been working on.

Comment: Unclear to me what your required output is. (other seem to have understood, good for you!). .... `man grep` and read about the `-f , -A, -B, -C` options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way, let `names.txt` content be

```
XP_037759835.2
XP_037759838.2
XP_037759836.2
```

and `file.txt` content be

```
>NP_001277599.1 actin, alpha cardiac muscle 1 [Chelonia mydas]
MCDDEETTALVCDNGSGLVKAGFAGDDAPRAVFPSIVGRPRHQGVMVGMGQKDSYVGDEAQSKRGILTLKYPIEHGIITN
WDDMEKIWHHTFYNELRVAPEEHPTLLTEAPLNPKANREKMTQIMFETFNVPAMYVAIQAVLSLYASGRTTGIVLDSGDG
VTHNVPIYEGYALPHAIMRLDLAGRDLTDYLMKILTERGYSFVTTAEREIVRDIKEKLCYVALDFENEMATAASSSSLEK
SYELPDGQVITIGNERFRCPETLFQPSFIGMESAGIHETTYNSIMKCDIDIRKDLYANNVLSGGTTMYPGIADRMQKEIT
ALAPSTMKIKIIAPPERKYSVWIGGSILASLSTFQQMWISKQEYDEAGPSIVHRKCF
>NP_001277600.1 cytochrome P450 1A [Chelonia mydas]
MSLLGSQGIISVTEILIASAVFCLTFMVIRSFRQQIPKGLKRLPGPRGYPLIGNLLELGSNPHLTLTQMSQKYGDVMQIR
IGTRPVLVLSGLDTIKQALVKQGEDFMGRPDLYSFHHVADGQSLTFSTDSGEVWRARRKLAQNALKTFSVSPSPNSSSTC
LLEEHVSKEADYLVRKLLQLMEEKKRFDPFRYVVVSVANVICAMCFGNRYDHDDQELLSIVNVTEEFGDVAASGNPVDFI
PVLQYLPNRTMKKFMEFNTRFLRLLQDIVKEHYESFEKDNIRDITDSLIEQSQENKVEANANIQLPKGKIINLVNDLFGA
GFDTVTTALSWSLMYLVTYPDIQKKIQEELDQTIGRERRPRLSDRPMLPYTEAFILEMFRHSSFLPFTIPHCTTKDTVLN
GYYIPKDLCVFVNQWQVNHDEKLWKEPSRFDPERFLRAGGTEVNKTDGEKILIFGLGKRKCLGETIARWEVFLFLTTLLQ
QLEFSISDGQKVDMTPLYGLTMKHKRCEHFQVKQRFPIQSSE
>NP_001277601.1 tumor susceptibility gene 101 protein [Chelonia mydas]
MAVRESELKKMLAKYKYRDLTVQETTSVITQYKDLKPVMDAYVFNDGSSRDLMSLTGTIPVPYRGNTYNIPICLWLLDTY
PFNPPICFVKPTSSMTIKTGKHVDANGKIYLPYLHEWKHPQSDLIGLIQIMIVVFGEEPPVFSRPTISTSFQPYQATGPP
NTSYMPGMPSGISPYPPGHPPNPSGYPGYPYPPGGPFPATTSGQHYTSQPPVTTVGPSRDGTISEDTIRASRISAVSDKL
RWRMKEEMDRAQAELNALKRTEEDLKKGHQKLEEMVTRLDHEVAEVDKNIELLKKKDEELSSALEKMENQSENNDIDEVI
IPTAPLYKQILNLYAEENAIEDTIFYLGEALRRGVIDLDVFLKHVRLLSRKQFQLRALMQKARKTAGLSDLY
>XP_037759835.2 splicing factor 1 isoform X1 [Chelonia mydas]
MAATGANATPLGKLHPPPPPGKPGYPMPPPGPPGLVLPGPPPPPPPGPGQAQAALLGPMAAAAYPFAALPPPPPPPPPPP
PPPQPQPPPQQPQPPPPPPPPPPPQQQQPPPQAGGPQPPPQYGQYRYPSPPPPPQGHEQQQPPPPQQQQQDESGPGGGSN
HDFPNKKRKRSRWNQDTMEQKTVIPGMPTVIPPGLTREQERAYIVQLQIEDLTRKLRTGDLGIPPNPEDRSPSPEPIYNS
EGKRLNTREFRTRKKLEEERHNLITEMVALNPDFKPPADYKPPATRVSDKVMIPQDEYPEINFVGLLIGPRGNTLKNIEK
ECNAKIMIRGKGSVKEGKVGRKDGQMLPGEDEPLHALVTANTMENVKKAVEQIRNILKQGIETPEDQNDLRKMQLRELAR
LNGTLREDDNRILRPWQSAETRSITNTTVCTKCGGAGHIASDCKFSRPGDPQSAQDKARMDKEYLSLMAELGEAPVPASV
GSSSGPTNTPLSSGPRPSGPGNNPPPPNRPPWMNSGPSDNRPYHGMHGGPGGPGGPHNFHHPMPNMGGHGGHPMQHNPNG
PPPWMQPHHPPMNQGPHPPGHPGPHHMDQYLGNTPVGSGVYRLHQGKGMMPPPMGMMAPPPPPPSGQPPPPPSGPLPPWQ
QQQQPPPPPPSSSMASSTPLPWQQNTTTTTTTSAGTGSIPPWQQQGAAVAASTGAPQMQGNPSMVPLPPGVQPPLPPGAP
PPPPPPPPGSAGMMYAPPPPPPPMDPSNFVTMMGMGVPALPPFGMPPAPPPPPPQN
>XP_037759838.2 splicing factor 1 isoform X4 [Chelonia mydas]
MAATGANATPLGKLHPPPPPGKPGYPMPPPGPPGLVLPGPPPPPPPGPGQAQAALLGPMAAAAYPFAALPPPPPPPPPPP
PPPQPQPPPQQPQPPPPPPPPPPPQQQQPPPQAGGPQPPPQYGQYRYPSPPPPPQGHEQQQPPPPQQQQQDESGPGGGSN
HDFPNKKRKRSRWNQDTMEQKTVIPGMPTVIPPGLTREQERAYIVQLQIEDLTRKLRTGDLGIPPNPEDRSPSPEPIYNS
EGKRLNTREFRTRKKLEEERHNLITEMVALNPDFKPPADYKPPATRVSDKVMIPQDEYPEINFVGLLIGPRGNTLKNIEK
ECNAKIMIRGKGSVKEGKVGRKDGQMLPGEDEPLHALVTANTMENVKKAVEQIRNILKQGIETPEDQNDLRKMQLRELAR
LNGTLREDDNRILRPWQSAETRSITNTTVCTKCGGAGHIASDCKFSRPGDPQSAQDKARMDKEYLSLMAELGEAPVPASV
GSSSGPTNTPLSSGPRPSGPGNNPPPPNRPPWMNSGPSDNRPYHGMHGGPGGPGGPHNFHHPMPNMGGHGGHPMQHNPNG
PPPWMQPHHPPMNQGPHPPGHPGPHHMDQYLGNTPVGSGVYRLHQGKDTTTTTTTSAGTGSIPPWQQQGAAVAASTGAPQ
MQGNPSMVPLPPGVQPPLPPGAPPPPPPPPPGSAGMMYAPPPPPPPMDPSNFVTMMGMGVPALPPFGMPPAPPPPPPQN
>XP_037759836.2 splicing factor 1 isoform X2 [Chelonia mydas]
MAATGANATPLGKLHPPPPPGKPGYPMPPPGPPGLVLPGPPPPPPPGPGQAQAALLGPMAAAAYPFAALPPPPPPPPPPP
PPPQPQPPPQQPQPPPPPPPPPPPQQQQPPPQAGGPQPPPQYGQYRYPSPPPPPQGHEQQQPPPPQQQQQDESGPGGGSN
HDFPNKKRKRSRWNQDTMEQKTVIPGMPTVIPPGLTREQERAYIVQLQIEDLTRKLRTGDLGIPPNPEDRSPSPEPIYNS
EGKRLNTREFRTRKKLEEERHNLITEMVALNPDFKPPADYKPPATRVSDKVMIPQDEYPEINFVGLLIGPRGNTLKNIEK
ECNAKIMIRGKGSVKEGKVGRKDGQMLPGEDEPLHALVTANTMENVKKAVEQIRNILKQGIETPEDQNDLRKMQLRELAR
LNGTLREDDNRILRPWQSAETRSITNTTVCTKCGGAGHIASDCKFSRPGDPQSAQDKARMDKEYLSLMAELGEAPVPASV
GSSSGPTNTPLSSGPRPSGPGNNPPPPNRPPWMNSGPSDNRPYHGMHGGPGGPGGPHNFHHPMPNMGGHGGHPMQHNPNG
PPPWMQPHHPPMNQGPHPPGHPGPHHMDQYLGNTPVGSGVYRLHQGKGMMPPPMGMMAPPPPPPSGQPPPPPSGPLPPWQ
QQQQPPPPPPSSSMASSTPLPWQQSEYDDHHHHERWHRVHPAMAAAGGCGGGFYGGPADARQPLHGPFASRGPASAAARG
PAAAAAAAAWLRGHDVRPAPSPAPHGPF
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=">";OFS="|";ORS=""}FNR==NR{$1=$1;regex=$0;next}$0~regex{print ">" $0}' names.txt file.txt
```

gives output

```
>XP_037759835.2 splicing factor 1 isoform X1 [Chelonia mydas]
MAATGANATPLGKLHPPPPPGKPGYPMPPPGPPGLVLPGPPPPPPPGPGQAQAALLGPMAAAAYPFAALPPPPPPPPPPP
PPPQPQPPPQQPQPPPPPPPPPPPQQQQPPPQAGGPQPPPQYGQYRYPSPPPPPQGHEQQQPPPPQQQQQDESGPGGGSN
HDFPNKKRKRSRWNQDTMEQKTVIPGMPTVIPPGLTREQERAYIVQLQIEDLTRKLRTGDLGIPPNPEDRSPSPEPIYNS
EGKRLNTREFRTRKKLEEERHNLITEMVALNPDFKPPADYKPPATRVSDKVMIPQDEYPEINFVGLLIGPRGNTLKNIEK
ECNAKIMIRGKGSVKEGKVGRKDGQMLPGEDEPLHALVTANTMENVKKAVEQIRNILKQGIETPEDQNDLRKMQLRELAR
LNGTLREDDNRILRPWQSAETRSITNTTVCTKCGGAGHIASDCKFSRPGDPQSAQDKARMDKEYLSLMAELGEAPVPASV
GSSSGPTNTPLSSGPRPSGPGNNPPPPNRPPWMNSGPSDNRPYHGMHGGPGGPGGPHNFHHPMPNMGGHGGHPMQHNPNG
PPPWMQPHHPPMNQGPHPPGHPGPHHMDQYLGNTPVGSGVYRLHQGKGMMPPPMGMMAPPPPPPSGQPPPPPSGPLPPWQ
QQQQPPPPPPSSSMASSTPLPWQQNTTTTTTTSAGTGSIPPWQQQGAAVAASTGAPQMQGNPSMVPLPPGVQPPLPPGAP
PPPPPPPPGSAGMMYAPPPPPPPMDPSNFVTMMGMGVPALPPFGMPPAPPPPPPQN
>XP_037759838.2 splicing factor 1 isoform X4 [Chelonia mydas]
MAATGANATPLGKLHPPPPPGKPGYPMPPPGPPGLVLPGPPPPPPPGPGQAQAALLGPMAAAAYPFAALPPPPPPPPPPP
PPPQPQPPPQQPQPPPPPPPPPPPQQQQPPPQAGGPQPPPQYGQYRYPSPPPPPQGHEQQQPPPPQQQQQDESGPGGGSN
HDFPNKKRKRSRWNQDTMEQKTVIPGMPTVIPPGLTREQERAYIVQLQIEDLTRKLRTGDLGIPPNPEDRSPSPEPIYNS
EGKRLNTREFRTRKKLEEERHNLITEMVALNPDFKPPADYKPPATRVSDKVMIPQDEYPEINFVGLLIGPRGNTLKNIEK
ECNAKIMIRGKGSVKEGKVGRKDGQMLPGEDEPLHALVTANTMENVKKAVEQIRNILKQGIETPEDQNDLRKMQLRELAR
LNGTLREDDNRILRPWQSAETRSITNTTVCTKCGGAGHIASDCKFSRPGDPQSAQDKARMDKEYLSLMAELGEAPVPASV
GSSSGPTNTPLSSGPRPSGPGNNPPPPNRPPWMNSGPSDNRPYHGMHGGPGGPGGPHNFHHPMPNMGGHGGHPMQHNPNG
PPPWMQPHHPPMNQGPHPPGHPGPHHMDQYLGNTPVGSGVYRLHQGKDTTTTTTTSAGTGSIPPWQQQGAAVAASTGAPQ
MQGNPSMVPLPPGVQPPLPPGAPPPPPPPPPGSAGMMYAPPPPPPPMDPSNFVTMMGMGVPALPPFGMPPAPPPPPPQN
>XP_037759836.2 splicing factor 1 isoform X2 [Chelonia mydas]
MAATGANATPLGKLHPPPPPGKPGYPMPPPGPPGLVLPGPPPPPPPGPGQAQAALLGPMAAAAYPFAALPPPPPPPPPPP
PPPQPQPPPQQPQPPPPPPPPPPPQQQQPPPQAGGPQPPPQYGQYRYPSPPPPPQGHEQQQPPPPQQQQQDESGPGGGSN
HDFPNKKRKRSRWNQDTMEQKTVIPGMPTVIPPGLTREQERAYIVQLQIEDLTRKLRTGDLGIPPNPEDRSPSPEPIYNS
EGKRLNTREFRTRKKLEEERHNLITEMVALNPDFKPPADYKPPATRVSDKVMIPQDEYPEINFVGLLIGPRGNTLKNIEK
ECNAKIMIRGKGSVKEGKVGRKDGQMLPGEDEPLHALVTANTMENVKKAVEQIRNILKQGIETPEDQNDLRKMQLRELAR
LNGTLREDDNRILRPWQSAETRSITNTTVCTKCGGAGHIASDCKFSRPGDPQSAQDKARMDKEYLSLMAELGEAPVPASV
GSSSGPTNTPLSSGPRPSGPGNNPPPPNRPPWMNSGPSDNRPYHGMHGGPGGPGGPHNFHHPMPNMGGHGGHPMQHNPNG
PPPWMQPHHPPMNQGPHPPGHPGPHHMDQYLGNTPVGSGVYRLHQGKGMMPPPMGMMAPPPPPPSGQPPPPPSGPLPPWQ
QQQQPPPPPPSSSMASSTPLPWQQSEYDDHHHHERWHRVHPAMAAAGGCGGGFYGGPADARQPLHGPFASRGPASAAARG
PAAAAAAAAWLRGHDVRPAPSPAPHGPF
```

Explanation: when processing 1st file (`FNR==NR`) I built `regex` by joining newline separated fields using pipe (`|`) which means alternative (OR) and instruct GNU `AWK` to go to `next` line so nothing other happens when processing files, when processing following files I `print` line if it does match `regex` and I prepend it `>` as it was consumed due to being row separator (`RS`). **Dislcaimer**: this solution assumes that there are not spaces in first file and characters of special meaning in regular expression are not problem (e.g. here `.` are treated as any character).

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue!

```
perl -we '
    open my $in, "<", "Name.txt" or die $!;
    chomp(@lines = <$in>);
    @names{@lines} = ();
    open $seq, "<", "sequence.faa" or die $!;
    while (<$seq>) {
        if (/>(\S+)/) { $output = exists $names{$1}; }
        print if $output;
    }'
```

It reads the Name.txt into a hash table `%names`. Then it processes the sequences, using `$output` as a flag: if a sequence was met in the names, the flag is set to 1 and we start printing the lines. If a new sequence starts that was not mentioned, we stop printing.

Comment: Didnt realize that perl can tackle this task easily, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You could imagine making a single line per block with `sed` in order to use `grep` to select the values.
At the end, you would generate back the block from the lines selected.

`,,++` is an arbitrary string used to encode `<new line>`

Give this a try:

```
sed -n '
  :1
  /^>[A-Z][A-Z]_[0-9]/ {
    x
    /./ {
      s/\n/,,++/g
      p
    }
    n
    b 1
  }
  H
  ${
    x
    /./ {
      s/\n/,,++/g
      p
    }
  }' sequence.faa | grep -Ff Name.txt | sed 's/,,++/\n/g'
```

There is this great page for `sed` scripts: [Sed - An Introduction and Tutorial by Bruce Barnett](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

Comment: Seems a bit difficult, I guess I have to learn sed script first lol

Comment: @Dr.Coke: ha !The script is cryptic ...and funny thought! ```x``` ```n``` ```b``` ```p``` ```s``` ```H``` are a sub-set of the ```sed```'s commands, which make you feel the script is obfuscated some how.

Answer (score 1):

Simple `grep` and `parallel` at work:

`cat Name.txt | parallel 'grep -zo ">{}[^>]*" sequence.faa'`

Exact same output as you want.

Comment: what does -zo do?

Comment: You can refer the `man grep` for this. `-z` will consider multiple lines for pattern matching and `-o` will output only matched text. :)